# Is there any way to get the displayed text in the "Select List" without using SQL? (Oracle APEX 21.1)

Tags: oracle-apex

Anyone help me?

"Select List" (name: P2_SHOPS_LIST) that is created with the following SQL
`SQL Statement: SELECT SHOP_NAME, GROUP_ID FROM T_ENTRY_SHOPS WHERE ID=:P2_LOV_ID;`

It is necessary "GROUP_ID" because it is PK . But I need edit "SHOP_NAME" value and display to Text Field.

I think I can get the currently displayed SHOP_NAME by combining the above SQL with the selection row number, but is there any way to access this value with No SQL? Like

> :P2_SHOPS_LIST.SHOP_NAME

(This gave me an error XD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of JavaScript, you can use the following

```
$('#P2_SHOPS_LIST option:selected').text()
```

This can be passed through to PL/SQL via a dynamic action, such as on change of your select list.

Or you could set your text item on change via a JS based action, using 'Set Value' and that code as the expression.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness!
This was my first time editing a JavaScript. But I just copy-pasted the code you wrote, it worked exactly!

Comment: There's lots of little one-liners like this I use all the time - small things that go a long way.